# 10 GB Raster Aerial Image in Quantum and POSTGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, image, aerial-photography

I have a problem... I have been successful in uploading the raster in postgis but when I access it through Qgis. it does not open even after several hours.

I have 10GB aerial image raster and everytime i try to open it through QGIS it does not open even after many hours and QGIS crashes...

why is this happening...?? is it really due to the file size..??

Regards,
Omer

Comment: How did you load (correctly) the file into postgis? Is it indexed - do request a small area spatially?

Comment: This is also posted on the qgis-user mailing list... http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2013-August/023617.html

Comment: You're loading it and then trying to view the whole extent in QGIS? Yes, it's the file size. You can't view a 10G image without overviews, and your database raster probably doesn't have overviews built. If you're just looking at it, leave it as a file and access it there, it'll be loads faster and even will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raster was loaded properly in Postgis with overviews but qgis plugin "Add a Postgis Raster layer" can't handle this file due to the size (10GB). However, I was successful in adding a subset of that raster whose size was comparatively very small.
QGIS displays that raster correctly. I have tried raster having maximum 3GB size.
If anyone has succeeded with more than this size, kindly post a comment here

Answer (score 0):

Try building a virtual raster and pyramids from the original. Qgis should then only load the visible part into memory.

See http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdalbuildvrt-setting-scale-dependent-visibility-td5095071.html for details